# Orchard CMS: Sign Out (Log Off) Confirmation Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Is there an event that gets fired when a user logs off of the front end and how can I use that event to redirect the user to a particular view or page?  I would like the user to receive a message that says, "You have successfully logged off" after they sign out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always, there is more than one way to do this with Orchard :)

**Method 1: Overriding the user shape**

When you log off, you are redirected to an action method on `Orchard.Users.AccountController` called `LogOff`, which takes a `returnUrl` argument. The shape that contains the sign out link  is under `~/Core/Shapes/Views/User.cshtml` but you can override this by creating a copy of it in your theme called `Views/User.cshtml` (or use the shape tracing module to find this shape and create an alternate).

In your copy all you then have to do is change

```
@Html.ActionLink(T("Sign Out").ToString(), "LogOff", new { Controller = "Account", Area = "Orchard.Users", ReturnUrl = Context.Request.RawUrl }, new { rel = "nofollow" })
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink(T("Sign Out").ToString(), "LogOff", new { Controller = "Account", Area = "Orchard.Users", ReturnUrl = "/My/LogOff/Confirmation/Page" }, new { rel = "nofollow" })
```

**Method 2: IUserEventHandler**

For a more dynamic requirement, you could implement the `Orchard.Users.Events.IUserEventHandler` interface, redirecting to your confirmation page when the `LoggedOut` method is called:

```
public class LoggedOutRedirect : IUserEventHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    public LoggedOutRedirect(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public void LoggedOut(IUser user)
    {
        _httpContext.Current().Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com/");
    }

    public void Creating(UserContext context) { }
    public void Created(UserContext context) { }
    public void LoggedIn(IUser user) { }
    public void AccessDenied(IUser user) { }
    public void ChangedPassword(IUser user) { }
    public void SentChallengeEmail(IUser user) { }
    public void ConfirmedEmail(IUser user) { }
    public void Approved(IUser user) { }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Where do I insert method two?  Thank you.

Comment: Well, you would create a new class file in one of your modules and add the code above. You'll also need to add empty implementations for all the other IUserEventHandler methods for it to compile.

Comment: I just put a new file called "class.cs" in "any" module folder?  I don't understand what an empty implementation is, either.  Do you have any examples or tutorials you can link me to?  Thanks.

Comment: No, if you have a module then you would create a file called LoggedOutRedirect.cs in the relevant module's folder. If you don't have a module, you could create one. By empty implementations I mean that you need to define all the methods on IUserEventHandler in order to satisfy the interface definition, but you don't need to put code in all the methods (just the relevant ones, in this case LoggedOut).

Comment: Look at the first couple of steps in this guide if you need to create a module: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module

Comment: So, the point of that would be to create a module (maybe called CustomLogout) and put the method two code in a file called LoggedOutRedirect.cs which would override the core's LoggedOutRedirect.cs.  But, I will have to also define blank methods from the IUserEventHandler class?  How can I find these methods?

Comment: Not quite, there is no core LoggedOutRedirect.cs. IUserEventHandler is an interface. Orchard automatically notifies any classes that have the IUserEventHandler interface when certain events occur. So by defining your own class that implements the IUserEventHandler interface, you are subscribing to those events. You can get Visual Studio to write most of the class for you by clicking on IUserEventHandler in your class definition (click it where it says `LoggedOutRedirect : IUserEventHandler`) and press Ctrl-., then choose 'Implement interface IUserEventHandler' :)

Comment: I've edited the answer and added a complete example, which you can just copy and paste into the new class file.

Comment: Cool, thank you.  The only thing I don't understand as of yet is how where to put it.  Do I create a new module for this or do I put this file (called "LoggedOutRedirect.cs") in an existing module?  If so, which module, does it matter?

Comment: Create a new module, else you run the risk of your code being wiped out when Orchard's modules are updated.