# Where is IUserEventHandler located in Orchard 1.6?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am attempting to extend the Orchard login process using IUserEventHandler, like is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585608/orchard-cms-sign-out-log-off-confirmation-page).  No matter how hard I look through the Orchard assemblies, I can't find the Orchard.Users.Events namespace which is the supposed home of IUserEventHandler.

Which Orchard assembly contains that interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.  It is actually an Orchard Module, available under /Modules/Orchard.Users.